# How to update data if same key exists in mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am inserting data from `CSV` file, I want to update if the object key has the same then the new price will just update, I have used `csvtojson` for parsing CSV files and `multer` for file upload.

CSV file has itemNumber, title, and price column

**sample.csv**

```
itemNumber,title,price
STY0047,Men Straight Fit Jeans,2500
STY0048,Men Straight Fit Jeans,2450
STY0049,Men Straight Fit Jeans,2550
STY0050,Men Straight Fit Jeans,3000
STY0048,Men Straight Fit Jeans,4000
STY002,Men Straight Fit Jeans,2550
STY0053,Men Straight Fit Jeans,3000
STY0054,Men Straight Fit Jeans,3000
STY0043,Men Straight Fit Jeans,4000
```

**My code**

```
router.post("/file-insert-data", upload, async function (req, res, next) {

  if (!req.file) {
    return res.status(400).send("no file found");
  }

  const results = await csv().fromFile(req.file.path);

  for (let obj in results ) {
      const csvData = new csvModel(results [obj])

      csvData.save((err, data) => {
        if(err) {
          return res.status(400).send("csv data is not inserted")
        }
        return res.status(201).send(data)
      })
    }
  
});
```

**Help me Thanks**

Comment: Can you post the result of a `console.log(results)` after you read your csv file?

Comment: I am getting array which is saved in sample.csv file,
`[
  {
    itemNumber: 'DNFJAV001-SK-STY0047',
    title: 'Men Straight Fit Jeans',
    price: '2500'
  },
  {
    itemNumber: 'DNFJAV001-SK-STY0048',
    title: 'Men Straight Fit Jeans',
    price: '2450'
  }
]`
more object has but i cants post it here as you know more lines ar not acceptable as comment

Comment: What about the `mongoimport` tool? It supports CSV files and also upsets.

Comment: Please edit your question for such additional information instead of putting it as comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Try to use the `findOne` function to check if the element already exists (I assume that `itemNumber` is key for the model).
2. If not, create a new instance of `csvModel`
3. Update the price
4. Save the data

```
router.post('/file-insert-data', upload, async function (req, res, next) {
  if (!req.file) {
    return res.status(400).send('no file found');
  }

  try {
    const results = await csv().fromFile(req.file.path);
    let updatedData = []; // Array to store the updated data
    for (const item of results) {
      const { itemNumber, title, price } = item;
      let csvData = await csvModel.findOne({ itemNumber });
      if (!csvData) {
        // Create new data if not present
        csvData = new csvModel();
        csvData.itemNumber = itemNumber;
        csvData.title = title;
      }
      // Update the price
      csvData.price = price;

      // Save the created / updated data
      await csvData.save();

      updatedData.push(csvData);
    }

    return res.status(201).send(updatedData);
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).send('Error updating data');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

UPDATED

After some collab with the OP, here is mongoose-friendly version that aligns with the original question.   It highlights `upsert` functionality and features generic addition of new fields.

```
results.forEach(function (item) {
var prx = item['price'];  // capture price....

    // ...and now REMOVE it.  This is because fields cannot appear in                               
    // both $set and $setOnInsert.  Our trick here is to make the $setOnInsert                         
    // generic.  ANY fields that are NOT itemNumber or price will automatically                     
    // be added upon first insert.  It should be obvious that if you need                           
    // to upsert more things (i.e. more things to $set), then delete them from                      
    // the object too.  Note: $setOnInsert will only store the fields from                          
    // item upon first insert.  New fields in later items with an existing                          
    // key will NOT be updated.  Comment out the delete and see the error
    // message re. path conflict:                                                                    
delete item['price'];

rc = csvModel.findOneAndUpdate(
{ itemNumber: item["itemNumber"] },
{
$set: { price: prx },
$setOnInsert: item // Ah! Set the WHOLE OBJECT.
},
{ upsert: true }
);
rc.then(data => data)
});
```

Comment: please tell me the means of rc

Comment: rc is just the return code from the call to `updateOne`.  You can do `printjson(rc);` to see the info returned.   It is not essential to this example.

Comment: if i use csvModel instead of db.foo it will work because i am doing this with mongoose

Comment: I cautiously say "yes."   There is nothing here that messes with Promises and such.  I am not a mongoose expert.   Is `csvData` a  javascript object?  If so, that seems to be the replacement for `item` in answer above.

Comment: i got the rc value as a promise pending

Comment: Try putting `await` in there somewhere.   The key thing here is the `$set/$setOnInsert` functionality.   I cannot robustly help with `node.js` and mongoose and models and such.

Comment: ok i am trying thankyou

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240611/discussion-between-kamalesh-maity-and-buzz-moschetti).

Comment: This should work, however the performance would be quite bad.